# How to split IEnumerable<string> to groups by separator?

Tags: c#

I have `IEnumerable<string>` which represents txt file. 
Txt file have this structure: 
Number of group ( int ) 
WordOfGroup1 (string)
WordOfGroup2 
WordOfGroupN 
EmptyLine 
Number of group ( int ) 
WordOfGroup1 (string) 
etc.

I need create from this text `Dictionary<fistWordOfGroup(string), allWordsInGroup(List<string>)` 
How i can make that in linear complexity?

Comment: What is your attempt? We can help to fix your work but we won't do it for you. Showing your code also helps to understand what you want. Provide menaingful sample data and the expected result as well.

Comment: It's unclear what "I need create from this text `Dictionary<fistWordOfGroup(string),` `allWordsInGroup(List<string>)`" means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the algorithm below. This will add a group of words to the dictionary whenever it comes across an empty line.

```
List<string> input = new List<string>()
{
    "1",
    "wordOfGroup11",
    "wordOfGroup12",
    "wordOfGroup1N",
    "\n",
    "2",
    "wordOfGroup21",
    "wordOfGroup22",
    "\n"
};


Dictionary<string, List<string>> result = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
string firstWordOfGroup = "";
List<string> allWordsInGroup = new List<string>();

foreach (string line in input)
{
    if (int.TryParse(line, out int index) == true)
    {
        allWordsInGroup.Clear();
        continue;
    }
    // I don't know what "EmptyLine" means
    if (line == "\n" || line == Environment.NewLine || line == string.Empty)
    {
        result.Add(firstWordOfGroup, allWordsInGroup);
    }
    else
    {
        if (allWordsInGroup.Count == 0)
        {
            firstWordOfGroup = line;
        }

        allWordsInGroup.Add(line);
    }
}
```

Also note that if your groups can have the same first word (e.g. both starting with "WordOfGroup1" then you should use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, List<string>>>` because the dictionary does not store duplicate keys.